# xrandr --addmode doesn't add to the wanted output (DVI-I-0), instead adding to HDMI-0

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, xrandr

The monitor I use is a Samsung SyncMaster S24B300, and no matter what the heck I do, Ubuntu *refuses* to use 1920x1080 at 60hz for the output I want, despite my monitor (which is unrecognized by the system even after I added the most recent nvidia driver) supporting it. In fact, even weirder, when I follow the "xrandr --newmode "name" ","xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 name","xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --mode name" pattern, it lists under HDMI-0.

For reference, xrandr command

```
esupanitix@esupanitix-p6670t:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1152 x 864, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1152x864+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0* 
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x26e)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

But the xrandr command chain was

```
esupanitix@esupanitix-p6670t:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
esupanitix@esupanitix-p6670t:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1920x1080_60.00
//result:X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

I tried making a .sh file and seeing if that would help, then made it executeable as a program and linked to it in the startup manager.

```
#!/bin/bash

    xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
    xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1920x1080_60.00
    xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

Which resulted in the 1920x1080_60.00 mode being added to **hdmi-0** of all things. So, what do I do? I'm confused beyond all belief here, and my monitor has no drivers for anything besides Windows because surprise surprise, I'm using a freaking **Samsung** monitor. Am I able to use substitute drivers or would the computer not recognize the monitor regardless?

I've been digging and digging and digging through the forums for an answer, and so far they've worked more **against** me than for me, to the point of requiring a live CD for recovery; to the point of me having to use the CTRL+ALT+F2 command line to edit a file so that I can log in again, and overall just adding frustration to a matter that seems like it would be perfectly fine to do considering Windows is able to do this just fine **without** having a driver for this thing.

Comment: "HDMI-0 disconnected" you sure the monitor was connected when you took the `xrandr` output?

Comment: Yes, it was. There was no HDMI input on my computer, which is all the more odd. I added the HDMI 1920x1080 resolution using `esupanitix@esupanitix-p6670t:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1920x1080_60.00`, which is incredibly weird.

Comment: So, what's the current status?

Comment: What do you mean, current status? It's the same as it is in the question. This problem is so unusual to me that I'm scared that making any significant effort on my own to change it while I barely know about this operating system and its commands would require yet another clean install of Ubuntu. I can't add the 1920x1080 state for the DVI-I-0 output because for some reason Linux isn't recognizing it. It just reverts it to HDMI, but I don't have an HDMI output on my video card and I would like to use this monitor that works completely fine driverless on Windows in 1920x1080.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so do you recall that I own a Samsung SyncMaster S24B300? One of the reasons it had very bad capability is because Linux doesn't take kindly to "generic pnp monitors" apparently. My copy of that monitor did **not** come with driver software, and Samsung is still very finicky about giving drivers for anything other than Windows.

Install the drivers for any new monitors **as soon as you get them.** This will make them compatible with all resolutions as long as they are compatible with Linux. I had to wait until six months later when I bought myself a BenQ monitor that came with the drivers that I could use it with Linux. During installation, I realized that I used a DVI-to-VGA converter, so it was a DVI signal being confused as a VGA signal if that means anything.

Basically what I'm saying is that I've been wasting your time because I didn't have the driver software for my monitor.

tl;dr this problem could have been nonexistent were it not for Samsung not knowing how to make drivers compatible with other operating systems.